# Get all CNAME records with Ruby/Fog

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, fog, amazon-route53

I am using the ruby/fog to query all CNAME records or A records of my AWS Route53 account.

```
items = zone.records.all!.find { |r| r.type == 'CNAME' or r.type == 'A' }
```

However, only one records will be returned even I have multiple matched records.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `find` only returns 1 record.  The first record.  Try using `select` instead.

Find: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find

Select: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select

Comment: Yep, I think the data should be returned from `all!`. So switching to select should get you what you need.